# How can I pack 3-dimensional boxes in a container with given sizes

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, bin-packing

I'm faced with a specific 3-dimensional packing problem:

with given sizes of **no more than 10** oriented (they cannot be rotated) boxes and a container find a packaging if there is one.

The number of boxes is really small, so even some straightforward ideas might work.

Comment: Does ‘oriented’ here mean they might not be axis-aligned, or that they can be rotated, or something else? More information about your constraints, an example, and what you’ve tried so far would also improve this post.

Comment: It means that boxes can't be rotated, sizes are integers and they can be places only at integer coordinates.
I tried to come up with some 'smart' algorithm that goes through all possible placements, no luck so far...